# zsh: too many levels of symbolic links: gcc

Tags: gcc, zsh, symlink, gcc-warning, oh-my-zsh

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        16 Apr  6 13:10 g++ -> /usr/bin/g++-4.5
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel     14272 Feb 14  2014 gatherheaderdoc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        16 Apr  6 13:11 gcc -> /usr/bin/gcc-4.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        22 Jul  2  2014 gcc-4.2 -> /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        12 Apr  6 10:59 gcc-4.4 -> /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        12 Apr  6 11:17 gcc-4.5 -> /usr/bin/gcc
```

Hi, I'm kinda new to linux. So i need some help with this issue.
I updated a new version of gcc and when I tried to check the version using `gcc --version`, I get the following error, `zsh: too many levels of symbolic links: gcc`.

I ran `ls -l` on `/usr/bin` and I found the above pasted cyclic link. Could someone help me on how to resolve this?

Comment: What distribution? How did you upgrade gcc?

Comment: I used `brew install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this has already been covered in a previous answer, but, you can see you have /usr/bin/gcc which is linked to /usr/bin/gcc-4.5 which is linked to /usr/bin/gcc.  Circular.  So, zsh eventually stops going around and circles and gives you that message.  You need to erase /usr/bin/gcc* and then reinstall it?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to remove it now. Should I go ahead and install gcc all again?

Comment: I installed gcc48 now. When I run `gcc --version`, it says `zsh:command not found`. What might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 7):

## 100% SOLVED THE PROBLEM

**the issue lies in your relative paths.** I had a similar problem symlinking my Nginx configuration from `/usr/local/etc/nginx` to `/etc/nginx.` If you create your symlink like this:

```
cd /usr/local/etc
ln -s nginx/ /etc/nginx
```

You will in fact make the link `/etc/nginx -> /etc/nginx,` because the source path is relative to the link's path.

**The solution is as simple as using absolute paths:**

```
ln -s /usr/local/etc/nginx /etc/nginx
```

If you want to use relative paths and have them behave the way you probably expect them to, you can use pwd to put the current working directory path in, like so:

```
cd /usr/local/etc
ln -s "$(pwd)/nginx/" /etc/nginx
```

You would want to have the quotes around the path, to make sure things like spaces in your current path are escaped. Note that you must use double quotes when doing this, as $(pwd) will not be substituted if you use single quotes.